# AngularJS: could not access Object property in the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

this is my object that get from a service.

this is my controller.

```
var user = useroneService.getLoggedUser(user);
console.log(user);
```

[image]

```
console.log(user.data);
```

I got a `undefined` when I try to access the data. How do I access to the Object data?

user.service.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('app').service('userService',['authService', 'userTransformer','LoggedUser', function(authService, userTransformer, LoggedUser) {
  this.getLoggedUser = function(user){
    return authService.login(user).then(function (response) {
      var loggedUser = userTransformer.transform(response.data);
    });
  };
}]);
```

logged.user.js

```
angular.module('app').value('LoggedUser', function () {  
    var LoggedUser = function () {
        this.dispalyName = '';
        this.token = '';
        this.logged = false;
    };  
    LoggedUser.prototype = {    
    };
});
```

user.transformer.js

```
angular.module('app').factory('userTransformer',['LoggedUser', function (LoggedUser) {
  //logged user transform
  var transformObject = function (response) {
    var model = new LoggedUser();
    angular.extend(model, response);
    return model;
  };
  return {
    transform: transformObject
  };
}]);
```

flow

```
AuthService(get data)==>UserService(data transform to LoggedUser using the transformer)
    ==>LoginController
```

Comment: Please post the code of your service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning a promise. Change your controller code to:

```
useroneService.getLoggedUser(user).then(function(data) {
    var user = data;
    console.log(user);
})
```

One more thing, you are not returning the response from your service:

```
return authService.login(user).then(function (response) {
  var loggedUser = userTransformer.transform(response.data);
  return loggedUser; //add this
});
```